# How to send a slice to a function in Go?

Tags: c, go

I'm rewriting some C code in Go. And in my C code I have stuff like this:

```
static void sharedb(unsigned char *sharedkey, unsigned char *send,
                    const unsigned char *received) {
    unsigned char krq[96]; 
    unsigned char buf[64];
    // rest removed for brevity

    indcpa_enc(send, buf, received, krq + 32);
}
```

Where `indcpa_enc` function is defined like this:

```
static void indcpa_enc(unsigned char *c,
                       const unsigned char *m,
                       const unsigned char *pk,
                       const unsigned char *coins)
```

So, in my Go code instead of using `char` arrays I used `byte` arrays. Where I have something like this:

```
func SharedB(sharedKey, send, received []byte) {
    var krq [96]byte
    var buf [64]byte

    // rest removed for brevity

    INDCPAEnc(send[:], buf[:SharedKeyBytes], received[:], krq[32:32+CoinBytes])
}
```

Where `INDCPAEnc` function is defined like this:

```
func INDCPAEnc(c []byte, m [SharedKeyBytes]byte, pk []byte, coins [CoinBytes]byte)
```

Though, this function call in Go gives me an array, regarding type mismatch. How can I convert a C code like above to a proper Go code? Also, should I use the pointer notation `*` for my Go function parameters as in C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters that specify a length (e.g. `[SharedKeyBytes]byte`) are arrays, not slices; therefor, you cannot pass a slice, hence the type mismatch error. You can either:

- Change the parameter type to slice (`[]byte`)
- Copy the slice to an appropriately-sized array prior to calling the function, then pass the array to the function instead of the slice ([playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/KEr23NVvUo))